# Is there a way to disable security on heroku Postgres db?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, heroku, heroku-cli

My project doesn't involve any private information, so I don't care about vulnerabilities.

I am certain that the connection between the App/server and the DB is the problem.
I tried to looking on Youtube and on Google, but the answers were outdated or they just didn't work for me. However, connecting to the database with heroku psql (cli) or connecting with pgAdmin4 using db creds and querying, creating tables works fine.

Following this guy's tutorial
`https://github.com/ousecTic/pern-deploy-tutorial`

Errors:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
});
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-02-12T11:02:33.058860+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275213+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/process/promises:265
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275240+00:00 app[web.1]: triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275241+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275241+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275241+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275242+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275242+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275242+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275243+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12) {
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275243+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
2022-02-12T11:02:34.275243+00:00 app[web.1]: }
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-02-12T11:19:13.660398+00:00 app[web.1]: { description: 'jhoipjo' } <<console.log() 
2022-02-12T11:19:13.681933+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.86.151.70", user "user", database "database", SSL off
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: false,
});
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2022-02-12T11:58:50.711988+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712007+00:00 app[web.1]: const message = name === 'notice' ? new messages_1.NoticeMessage(length, messageValue) : new messages_1.DatabaseError(messageValue, length, name);
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712008+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712009+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712010+00:00 app[web.1]: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.236.98.211", user "user", database "database", SSL off
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712010+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712011+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712012+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712013+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712014+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712014+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712014+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712014+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712015+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712015+00:00 app[web.1]: length: 166,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712016+00:00 app[web.1]: severity: 'FATAL',
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712016+00:00 app[web.1]: code: '28000',
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712016+00:00 app[web.1]: detail: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712017+00:00 app[web.1]: hint: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712017+00:00 app[web.1]: position: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712017+00:00 app[web.1]: internalPosition: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712018+00:00 app[web.1]: internalQuery: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712018+00:00 app[web.1]: where: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712018+00:00 app[web.1]: schema: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712018+00:00 app[web.1]: table: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712019+00:00 app[web.1]: column: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712019+00:00 app[web.1]: dataType: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712019+00:00 app[web.1]: constraint: undefined,
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712019+00:00 app[web.1]: file: 'auth.c',
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712019+00:00 app[web.1]: line: '496',
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712019+00:00 app[web.1]: routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
2022-02-12T11:58:50.712020+00:00 app[web.1]: }
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Vulnerabilities are not only used to steal private information... o.O

Comment: Sorry I am foreigner. I mean, the hobby/free tier does't have SSL and I don't now how to turn this off, hence the attempts above are trying to turn it off

Comment: And also in the Dashboard>Data>Utilization section it says CONNECTIONS 0 of 20

Comment: "My project doesn't involve any private information, so I don't care about vulnerabilities"—this is _not_ the right attitude.

Comment: "I mean, the hobby/free tier does't have SSL"—incorrect. I think you're thinking of HTTPS for custom domains, but that's _entirely_ different than the connection to your database.

Comment: Please show more than just `const pool = ...`. What libraries and imports are you using? What is `Pool`? Don't turn SSL off on your database connection, but you shouldn't be getting a self-signed certificate in the first place. How did you provision your database?

Comment: ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }, did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the app was a nodejs blogging app so there was no need for security

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
   
         ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
   
});
```